# Detecting if a command is executable by sudo

Tags: shell, sudo, io-redirection

I am wanting to detect in a shell script if a command I am going to run via sudo can in fact run via sudo. On newer versions of sudo I can do sudo -l "command" and this gives me exactly the result I want.

However, some of the systems have an old version of sudo in which -l "Command" isn't available. Another way I was thinking about doing it was to just try running the command then see if sudo prompted for the password. However, I do not see an easy way to do this as sudo writes the password prompt to the TTY and not via stdout.

Does anyone else know of a straight forward way to do this?

I should also mention "expect" doesn't seem to be available on the systems with the older sudo revisions, either.

Just for reference the "difficult" version of sudo appears to version 1.6.8

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, on (at least) Debian-like systems, you can have a look at `/etc/sudoers` (and the optional `/etc/sudoers.d/*` files, if created, and included in the main `/etc/sudoers`) that give (among others)

- the search path to where (which dir) a command can be issued
- the *sudo* user (root) privileges
- groups who can use *sudo* and their privileges

This is the [sudoers man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) for more information.

Comment: The sudoers file appears to be root:root or root:wheel 110 by default, so you won't be able to read it unless you can `sudo cat/less/view` it.

Comment: At least one `sudo cat /etc/sudoers` is necessary to see the file

Comment: If I just wanted to look in the sudoers file -- by hand -- I could just issue sudo -l by hand with no parameters and parse the wildcards. However, I need to do this an automated fashion. I just need the -n <command>or -l <command> functionality of sudo that the newer versions have on the older versions. I'm guessing its going to require doing something like taking the output sudo -l, writing it a file, converting the sudo patterns to regular expressions, and then running the command I want to execute against the regular expressions. More work then I'd like, but probably no way around it :/

Comment: For obvious security reasons, the files are readable by root. If you can get have access to root once...

Answer (score 0):

if you're only wanting to check that a password is required to run a command then you should be able to run:

```
$ sudo -n <command>
```

E.g.

```
$ sudo -n echo
sudo: sorry, a password is required to run sudo
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the -n switch only seems to exist on the same versions of sudo that support the -l switch.

Comment: What flags are available to your version?